# What is a good reference on Aristotle's views of friendship (φιλία)?

Tags: reference-request, aristotle, love, friendship

What is a good reference on Aristotle's views of friendship ([φιλία](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=greek&l=%CF%86%CE%B9%CE%BB%CE%AF%CE%B1#lexicon))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [*St. Thomas Aquinas, on Aristotle's Love and Friendship*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=8476), commentary on Aristotle's [*Ethics*, Books VIII](https://isidore.co/aquinas/Ethics8.htm) (Friendship) & [IX](https://isidore.co/aquinas/Ethics9.htm) (Properties of Friendship)